# Application is not continue the process after switch on the device

Tags: ios, iphone, background

I am implementing one application.In that application, I am going to switch off the device when the app is running and after some time I will switch on the device and open the same application. It's running from starting point, but I want to run from where I switch off the device. Please guide me how to achieve that one.

Comment: You should look into using [state restoration](https://www.raywenderlich.com/117471/state-restoration-tutorial)

Comment: I added the methods in APpdelegate,select the "use storyboard id" in storyboard and added the encode and decode methods in some view controllers.But not working

Comment: Is it work after switch off and on the device?